# Trying to remember a Tandy CoCo 2 point-and-click adventure game involving time travel within a museum

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, video-games

I have horribly vague memories of this, but lasting ones. I played it on a Radio Shack Tandy Color Computer 2 (maybe the CoCo 3, but I think it was the CoCo 2). It was a point-and-click adventure which included traveling back and forth in time. I am 90% certain that it was set in a museum. It was fairly monochrome, typical for the time. I remember traveling back to a medieval dungeon and also a situation where, to get the diamond, you had to take a lump of coal back in time, put it in a hydraulic press, then go forward in time until it became a diamond. I'm pretty sure one of the game screens had a vintage car on display.

It being on the CoCo 2 puts its publication somewhere between 1983 and 1986.

Comment: Possibly Off-Topic -- Inquiry specifically about a computer game (not the fictional world/setting that it is part of); may be best migrated to another SE site.

Comment: @K-H-W - Story Ident questions (about games) are on-topic, just about; http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4983/are-video-games-out-of-scope

Comment: @Richard -- Hmm.. Hadn't see that discussion; it still seems a poor fit at best, but since I can see the Sci-Fi, Fantasy aspects of it, VTC retracted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like *The Vortex Factor* (1985).

The description from [Moby Games](http://www.mobygames.com/game/vortex-factor) says:

> *The Vortex Factor* is an adventure about time travel. Your journey
>   begins in the halls of a rather large museum. Your goal in this
>   adventure is to find and collect nine (9) treasures scattered through
>   time and put them in the museum curator’s work room. You will move
>   forward and backward in time to achieve your goal.
>
> This graphical interactive fiction game uses standard single letter
>   directions, N, S, E, W, for movement. You can also SAVE your current
>   location on cassette for restarting later. The command parser is a
>   standard verb-noun type (Go Door). Once you have all of the items in
>   the curator’s work room, type "score" - you win if you accumulated 100
>   points.

Which sounds lot like what you described, although it is not a point and click adventure.

There are screenshots [here](http://www.mobygames.com/game/vortex-factor/screenshots):

[image: Science expo]
[image: Time Machine]

Comment: Ha! That's it, I'm pretty sure. And you're right... that was not a point-and-click adventure.